# unexpected behavior with loops and goroutinues in go

Tags: for-loop, concurrency, go, goroutine

Why does this:

```
for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
    go func(i int) {
        fmt.Printf("%d", i)
    }(i)
}
```

prints 012

while this:

```
for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
    go func() {
        fmt.Printf("%d", i)
    }()
}
```

prints 333?

Comment: [Here's a playground example of this phenomenon](http://play.golang.org/p/Oc9pOsAvOp).

Comment: @kvu787: FYI, the second example can print anything from `[012]{3}`, not only `333`. The code is simply non deterministic. That's what data race is for ;-)

Comment: @jnml has a good point. (Though typically 333 will be the result in this case.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While goroutines are cheap, they aren't free. There is some, but little, overhead in creating them.

In your first program, the value of `i` is preserved into the goroutines because you're passing it in as an argument. (Each goroutine gets its own copy of `i`'s value at that moment.)

In your second program, the value of `i` is already 3 before the first goroutine has started. Remember that goroutines share the same memory space in a Go program, so in this case, each goroutine is looking at the same `i` when it prints it out.

Answer (score 2):

Adding a print statement just after your `for` loop should makes things clear for you. You’ll see that that print statement runs before your goroutine function.

When all you do in a `for` loop is to launch a new goroutine, your loop passes very fast and usually finishes even before your first goroutine starts. So when your goroutines start your loop is already finished and the value of if `i` is `3`. Keep that in mind.

When you pass the `i` as a function argument, like you do in your first example, it’s current value is *copied* to the function stack, so the functions receives its current value as an argument. That’s why you’ll see `012`. But when a closure function just uses a variable in its surrounding scope, like you do in your second example, it accesses its current value when it is run, which in your case is after the loop has finished and `i` has reached `3`.

You can see this effect with this code:

```
for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
    go func(arg int) {
        fmt.Printf("%d %d\n", arg, i)
    }(i)
}
```

which produces this output:

```
0 3
1 3
2 3
```